# limit of $x \cot x$ as $x\to 0$.

Tags: calculus, limits

I was asked to calculate $$\lim_{x \to 0}x\cot x  $$
 I did it as following (using L'Hôpital's rule):
$$\lim_{x\to 0} x\cot x = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x \cos x}{\sin x} $$ We can now use L'Hospital's rule since the limit has indeterminate form $\frac{0}{0}$. Hence $$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(x \cos x)'}{(\sin x)'}   &= \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-x\sin x + \cos x}{\cos x} \\ &= \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-x\sin x}{\cos x} + 1 \\[4pt ]&= \lim_{x\to 0} - x \tan x + 1 \\[4pt] &= 1 \end{align}$$
I think that the result is correct but are the arguments correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to MSE! As best as I can tell your reasoning is sound, although as other users pointed out you could have done this in a few less steps. Regardless, your work is clear and your answer is correct. On an aside I am happy to see that you formatted your question with $\LaTeX$. I added some additional formatting to clean things up a bit, but overall nicely done.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: rewrite your term in the form
$$\frac{\cos(x)}{\frac{\sin(x)}{x}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice,$$\lim_{x\to 0}xcotx  $$  $$=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{x}{\tan x}\right)=1 $$  Or using L-Hospital's rule for $\frac{0}{0}$ form as follows $$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{x}{\tan x}\right)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{d(x)}{dx}}{\frac{d}{dx}(\tan x)}$$ $$=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{\sec^2x}=\frac{1}{\sec^2(0)}=\frac{1}{1}=1$$

Answer (score 0):

You could have stopped at
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos(x)-x\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}=\frac11
$$
but otherwise, your answer is fine.

---

**Moved from a Comment**

If you can use
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}x=1
$$
it would simplify the computation as well.